# skipping index file thumbs.db error in android

Tags: android

I was trying to import a android project to eclips. But i am getting the error like skipping index file thumbs.db in the thumbs.db file(in drawable folder).Many suggest to delete the thumbs.db file. how to resolve this? any issue if i am deleting this file?

Comment: What I tried to do was to create a new Android project with the same name and just drag and drop the src files in the correct packages, I know its tiring but it works!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a kind of Window Specific File.

It won't effect the Project,You can `delete without any Worries`.

Basic reason is when you Paste any Image into the `Drawable` folder/s, such file will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft windows create this Thumbs.db file to help it load the thumbnail of the image. This file has a name with capital letter in it 'T', android doesn't support capital letter for its drawables. Thats y it shows such an error. You can delete the file without any problem, This file will be again created when you again visit the drawable folder of the project.