# android - thumbs.db error

Tags: android, adt

My ADT version is 18.0. I got the thumbs.db file in drawable folder after cleaning the project and shows the error at that file(thumbs.db). After removing the thumbs.db then its working fine. Why this error came? How to handle this.

thanks

Comment: Your just missed same question 2 hours ago.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10892146/1298796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thumbs.db` is a file created by `Windows` when thumbnail view is used. It is a hidden file not viewed by most users and not updated when files are moved from a folder which images have passed through or deleted. This gives a secondary chance that someone will leave behind at least partial evidence of an image in their Windows folders.
The thumbnails in `Thumbs.db` are stored in the OLE Compound File format. It's the same format that Microsoft Office uses.

You can delete this file and run the Application.

Answer (score 0):

//in windows it will create

```
thumbs.db
```

delete the thumbs.db file and run it

click on Tools, and then Folder Options Just check Do not cache thumbnails [link here:](http://ask-leo.com/what_is_thumbsdb_and_can_i_delete_it.html)

Comment: Yes i am using windows. But what it mean what is the use of that.is there any way to stop that?